# Can't fetch CSS font

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, fonts, font-face

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Gotham";
  src: font_path("gotham-rounded-medium.otf") format("opentype");
}
```

I have this in my CSS file and I still can't fetch the font. Any help?

Comment: There are so many things that could go wrong, we need more information such as where the font file is retaliative to the html file, and where the css is located relative to the html.

Comment: Also where did you find the "font_path" variable? It should be `src: url("gotham-rounded-medium.otf") format("opentype");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify url, also I believe it's font-path, not font_path

`@font-face {
  font-family: "Gotham";
  src: url(font-path("gotham-rounded-medium.otf")) format("opentype");
}`

More here: http://aokolish.me/blog/2011/12/24/at-font-face-with-the-asset-pipeline/

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Gotham";
  src: url("gotham-rounded-medium.otf");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the font file is in your assets directory, try

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Gotham";
  src: url('/assets/gotham-rounded-medium.otf') format("opentype");
}
```